# OpenGL documentation source

Tags: opengl

I know that Khornos group owns opengl. However, both opengl.org and khronos.org domains host the documentation.

What is the official source of documentation for opengl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Khronos also owns the opengl.org domain. http://whois.domaintools.com/opengl.org

So both can be considered the official source of documentation though it's easier to find on the registry on https://www.opengl.org/registry/